# Using JavaFX in Swing to replace jEditorPame for HTML rendering

Tags: java, html, swing, javafx, jeditorpane

In an application, I'm using a jEditorPane component to display formatted text (by converting the text into a HTML-file). Since the HTML-rendering of jEditorPanes is fairly poor, I'm looking for a better alternative and found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218572/java-html5-alternative-to-jeditorpane).

Since I have no experience with JavaFX, my question is: do I still have the same possibilities like copying text selection, HyperLink-listeners, getting sources from drag&drop operations etc. as in a jEditorPane?

I would like to figure out whether these things are also possible when I integrate a JavaFX component into my Swing application *before* I start re-writing major parts of my source code...

To be a little bit more specific: I'm curious about which JavaFX "component" or object I have to use in order to replace my jEditorPane. Is it a [Scene](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html)?

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31576647/230513) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32396344/230513).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's probably a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it’s possible and more powerful. JavaFx library is some part more efficient and more flexible than swing; but it still need user’s experiences and it development is going slow for now.

Comment: here is an overview with samples: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-samples-2158687.html

Comment: ok, thanks! I guess I'll start to look for various examples that help me migrating from jEditorPane to JavaFX<something>. I'm just curious about which "component" or object I have to use in order to replace my jEditorPane. Is it a `scene`?

Comment: No, The scene is the main container of your application; the alternative to jEditorPane using to rendering HTML can be `WebView` which is like `QWebView` if you have experience with *Qt*. This is an example where you can see how the oracle web page is easily load on a JavaFX simple "browser": http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm

Comment: With JavaFX GUI application is like stage play . You have the Stage which is our theater, in it, you have the Scene and in the scene you have actors, etc which are node components. besides documentation and this site [http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/] the others tutorials i know is in french.